# What is the theorem being mentioned here?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pi9UiiF0ycU&t=5m5s) video, at just after the 5 minute mark, the speaker says:

> "...the colimit of the diagram has the homotopy type of the homotopy colimit. Why? Because all of the maps included in the diagram are closed cofibrations, and there is a theorem that if you have a diagram where everything is a closed cofibration, the homotopy type of the colimit and the homotopy colimit are the same."

What is the theorem being referenced here, or alternatively how does this follow?

**EDIT:**

If I have the following diagram:

$$* \rightrightarrows *$$
I think that this is a diagram of closed cofibrations for which the statement does not hold, for example.

I think the speaker's statement does hold in the particular type of cases that he is talking about, and that the maps in the diagrams he speaks of are closed cofibrations, but that there are extra conditions on the diagrams which he is not mentioning. I would like any further insight that anyone can offer (even in general, about diagrams whose colimits and hocolimits are homotopy equivalent).

Comment: This is not true. Certain special cases hold. Can you include some more context or a timestamp?

Comment: Ah, excuse me. I had meant to include the timestamp. It's at just after the 5 minute mark. I will edit this in to the question.

Comment: P.s. if anyone knows how to do that thing where the link to a youtube video actually takes you to a specific *time* in the video, I would like my link to do that, but I don't know how.

Comment: The statement the speaker is using is for filtered homotopy colimits. To add a timestamp, add &t=5m5s to the end of the link, or whatever specific minute/second mark you actually want.

Comment: Web Applications Stack Exchange: [Linking directly to a specific point in time of a YouTube video](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/732).

Comment: Your proposed counterexample is incorrect. The colimit and the homotopy colimit are both $S^2$. An actual counterexample is given by two parallel copies of the identity map of a point. The identity is certainly a closed cofibration, but the colimit is a point while the homotopy colimit is $S^1$. In fact every CW-complex is a homotopy colimit of a diagram consisting of identities of the point, while the colimit of any such diagram is a discrete space.

Comment: That is very true - I am not sure how I did not see that before. Thank you for these insightful remarks. I will edit to replace my "counterexample" with your counterexample.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Upon reflection, I don't actually think that what I've editted into the question as a counter example is a counter example at all. For what I've put there, I think that the homotopy colimit is still just a point (up to homotopy). Could you say more precisely what your counter example is?

Comment: Right, the homotopy colimit of that diagram is a point. My counterexample was rather $*\rightrightarrows *$.

Comment: Got it. Re-edited.